# Difference between std::cin and scanf() applied to string

Tags: c++, string, scanf, cin

I am trying to get the first character of a string written to a variable of type char. With std::cin (commented out) it works fine, but with scanf() I get runtime error. It crushes when I enter "LLUUUR". Why is it so? Using MinGW.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main() {
    std::string s;
    scanf("%s", &s);
    //std::cin >> s;
    char c = s[0];
}
```

Comment: Because `std::string` is not a `char*` (which `scanf` expects when you use `%s`)

Comment: What's the problem with using the code that works?  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scanf` knows nothing about `std::string`. If you want to read into the underlying character array you must write `scanf("%s", s.data());`. But do make sure that the string's underlying buffer is large enough by using `std::string::resize(number)`!

**Generally:** don't use `scanf` with `std::string`.

Another alternative if you want to use `scanf` and `std::string`

```
int main()
{
    char myText[64];
    scanf("%s", myText);

    std::string newString(myText);
    std::cout << newString << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Construct the string after reading.

Now for the way directly on the string:

```
int main()
{
    std::string newString;
    newString.resize(100); // Or whatever size   
    scanf("%s", newString.data());

    std::cout << newString << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

Although this will of course only read until the next space. So if you want to read a whole line, you would be better off with:

```
std::string s;
std::getline(std::cin, s);
```